# KRL: Getting the "location" header from an http:post()

Tags: http-headers, krl

I'm sending an HTTP POST request to a URL. It sends back a piece of information I need in the `location` header of the response. How do I get that header? I've tried the following code and it doesn't seem to work:

In the action block of the rule that uses the `http:post()` action:

```
http:post("https://cas.byu.edu/cas/v1/tickets/")
  with params = {"username": netid, "password": password}
  and autoraise = "gottgt"
  and response_headers = ["location"];
```

The rule that handles the `http` event:

```
rule got_tgt {
    select when http post label "gottgt"
    pre {
        content = event:param("content");
        location = event:param("location");
    }
    {
        notify("CAS Login", "Got back the POST response (#{location}): #{content}") with sticky=true;
    }
}
```

However, the `location` variable is always blank. How do I tell KRL that I want the `location` header, and how do I get it from the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't test your specific endpoint, I've built a sample app that you will find useful in debugging this issue.

Note that I'm both autoraising the response, and using the `setting` syntax to raise the events. You wouldn't normally do both, but it hilights a difference. When explicitly raising the result, you get the entire response. You can see in my example that the `server` header is returned, and shown also in the autoraised rule.

Your code looks right, but I'd do an explicit raise and inspect the response as I show here, and that will help you know exactly what is available to you.

Run this app here: http://ktest.heroku.com/a8x183

and code here:

```
ruleset a8x183 {
    meta {
        name "Testing Response Headers"
        description <<

        >>
        author "Sam Curren"
        logging off
    }

    dispatch {
        // domain "example.com"
    }

    global {
        bodylog = defaction(title, msg){
            {
            append("body", "<h1>#{title}</h1>");
            append("body", "<div>#{msg}</div>");
            }
        };
    }

    rule first_rule {
        select when pageview ".*" setting ()
        pre {

        }
        http:post("http://httpbin.org/post") setting (res)
            with params = {"username":"yahuda","password":"metalcages"}
            and autoraise = "kickstand"
            and response_headers = ["server"];
        fired {
            raise explicit event "moon" with res = res;   
        }
    }

    rule exp {
        select when explicit moon 
        pre {
            res = event:param("res");
            res_s = res.encode();
        }
        bodylog("explicit raise: full response", res_s);
    }

    rule response {
        select when http post label "kickstand"
        pre {
            server_header = event:param("server");
            content = event:param("content");
        }
        {
            bodylog("autoraise: content", content);
            bodylog("autoraise: server_header", server_header);
}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Raising the explicit event showed that the information is there. If I can't figure out how to do it the usual way, I'll just do that.